# Read the parmeters in a file when a script is executed with parameters

Tags: shell, unix

There is a directory in which multiple scripts are present. I want to read the parameter and store in a file. When someone run the scripts again, the parameter is appended to that file. Is that possible? Unix.

I have tried reading the number of times a file is executed and has done it. though I now want to read the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. (Maybe you should rephrase your question and add what you have tried)